# Rendering MSChart in MVC3 razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, charts, mschart, razor

I have a typical setup for displaying charts for MVC3 web page -

Here is the code for all the components.

### Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult ShowChart() {

     myViewModel model = _myService.GetViewModel();
     return View(model);
}
```

### View Model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;

public class ViewModel {

     public List<Chart> Charts { get; set; }

}
```

### View: (View.cshtml)

```
@foreach (System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart in Model.Charts)
{
    @chart
}
```

### Chart Builder:

This populates the View Model.

```
private List<Chart> BuildCharts(List<Dummy> chartData)
    {
        var charts = new List<Chart>();
        foreach (Dummy chart in chartData)
        {
            charts.Add(BuildChart(chart));
        }

        return charts;
    }

    private Chart BuildChart(Dummy chartData)
    {
        var data = new ChartData
        {
            Title = "Chart X",
            xValues = chartData.hours,
            yValues = chartData.values
        };

        return ConfigureChart(data);
    }

    private Chart ConfigureChart(ChartData data)
    {
        Chart chart = new Chart(); 
        chart.Width = 150; 
        chart.Height = 300; 
        chart.Attributes.Add("align", "left"); 
        chart.Titles.Add(data.Title); 
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
        chart.Series.Add(new Series());
        chart.Legends.Add(new Legend("XXXX_YYY"));
        chart.Legends[0].TableStyle = LegendTableStyle.Auto;
        chart.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
        chart.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

        chart.Series[0].BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalLeft;
        chart.Series[0].BackSecondaryColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.xValues.Length; i++)     
        {        
            string x = data.xValues[i];
            decimal y = data.yValues[i];

            int ptIdx = chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, y);

            DataPoint pt = chart.Series[0].Points[ptIdx];
            pt.Url = "/Instance/Index/";
            pt.ToolTip = "Tooltip";
            pt.LegendText = "#VALX: #VALY";
            pt.LegendUrl = "/Contact/Details/";
            pt.LegendToolTip = "Click to view dummy information...";
        }

        return chart; 
    }
```

But, the code - @chart in the view does not render the chart. what I get in the page is a string 'System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart' in place of the chart image.

Can somebody let me know what is wrong here. How can I output the chart on the view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do:

```
@chart
```

Asp.Net MVC does not know how to render those.  What you can do is either request each chart as an image. So follow [this tutorial](http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2008/11/27/howto-use-the-new-aspnet-chart-controls-with-aspnet-mvc/).

You should also move the "Option A" or "Option B" section into an [editor template](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/02/05/mvc-2-editor-template-with-datetime.aspx).

Comment: John,  Thank you for the tutorial link. I would try "Option B" as it seems more appropriate in my situation.

Comment: I don't see how this tutorial works w/Razor view engine.  Did this work for you?

Comment: Using the a different view engine doesn't make a difference.  I think you just need to wrap the code like this `@{ ...code... }`